# When choosing to boot into Safe Mode, Windows simply reboots. Why?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, safe-mode

I have a PC running Windows XP SP2, and I face a problem in it and need my PC to boot in safe mode.

But when I choose safe mode from the boot menu, my PC restarts automatically!
So what's the problem?

Comment: does it start loading a couple drivers and then restart? Can you hear anything odd? light clicking or grinding? I had a computer yesterday do this and it was a hd failing.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a [linux livecd](http://www.livecdlist.com/) (SystemRescueCD or Parted Magic) and see if you can mount the hd. If you can, back up your data before you start trying to fix anything.

Comment: Yes, it's loading some drivers and then restarts! and I don't hear anything odd!
Thanks for the link.

Any other ideas?

Comment: if you can mount the hd, you can run tests on the hd (SMART/TestDisk). HD could be failing, partition corrupted... alot of things. If the hd is fine, it would be easier to do a complete install. Recover data before you do anything...